# Connection.close() does not closes the connection, it make it sleep forever?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, tomcat8

In my web app which I write it with java and it uses tomcat and sql server, I can not close the database connections by typing connection.close(). When I write sp_who to the SSMS I can see that sleeping connections count which is opened by me increases while my app is doing sql stuffs.

An example code is in below:

```
BaseRepository baseRepository = new BaseRepository();
try{
    baseRepository.createStatement();

    baseRepository.stmt.executeUpdate("update AutoRunURLs set STATUS = 0");

}catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    baseRepository.cleanResources();
}
```

Here is the other functions that I used above:

```
public void openConnection() {
    try {
        this.conn = ds.getConnection(); // ds is an instance of javax.sql.DataSource
        this.isOpen = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public void createStatement() {
    try {
        if (!this.isOpen) this.openConnection();
        this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void cleanResources() {
    try {
        if (this.rs != null) {
            rs.close();
            this.rs = null;
        }
        if (this.stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
            this.stmt = null;
        }
        if (this.conn != null) {
            this.closeConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (this.conn != null) this.closeConnection();
    }
}

 public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        if (this.conn != null){
            this.conn.close();
        }
        this.isOpen = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the first part above which starts with `BaseRepository baseRepository ...` one sleeping connections occurs which I see with typing sp_who and it does not close(I waited about a day). Why is that? How can I prevent from this?

And I got one more situation. In my tomcat configurations I set the "maxIdle" value to 10 but even that sleeping connections increases up to thousands after a week. Why does maxIdle does not effect? Here is how I set it:

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" maxTotal="999999" maxIdle="10" "Database info here..." validationQuery="select 1"/>
<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
```

How can I solve these? Regards,

---

Edit: I actually managed it by creating a scheduled task which runs every x minutes and kills sleeping connections that sleeps over y minutes. But this is not the way I want. Any other solution will be great.

Comment: DB Connection and Java Resource to that connection is separate, in code you are only closing java ref to that db connection resource, what actually needs to be done with that resource in DB is handled by DB. At your level you can change max db connection count at tomcat level or data source level to control your inactive session count

Comment: @NishantModi Thanks for answer. By doing this, for example if set maxTotal to 100 and then after getting sleeping connections up to 100, the app does not responds as we can expect. So I can not bound it, what else can I do?

Comment: Sleeping connection doesn't mean that they wont serve the request. Sleeping connection will be activated and given to application when ever needed. If this is not your case and application is not getting the connection then there is certainly some other issue which is causing this.

Comment: @NishantModi Yes clearly there is some other issue about it. So what it can be?

Comment: are you sure application is not getting connection

Comment: @NishantModi I am not sure if it is getting connection or not, I just observe that app does not responses when connection count reaced to the max value. It does not reuse sleeping connections

Comment: Are you getting any connection related exception in logs

Comment: @NishantModi After getting sleeping connections that almost equal to max connection, it enteres the deadlock but not all the times.

Comment: how you are so sure about that, are you having any logs based on that you are concluding that

Comment: @NishantModi Yes I had a log that explains the deadlock, I do not have it now but the content of it was about that executing queries took so much times and it entered the deadlock. Query executions cant take that much time, it is because of connections, it could not get a connection instance.

Comment: deadlock is because of multiple query want to update same data. deadlock is not connection issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using a connection pool built into Tomcat. This means that it keeps connections open for reuse. When you close connections in your code, they aren't actually closed, but returned to the pool for re-use by your application. This increases efficiency because opening new connections takes time.

In other words, there is nothing wrong and the connections being kept open is **expected** behaviour.

You might want to decrease your `maxTotal` to a more sane value of say 10 - 20 instead of 999999 though.

As an aside, the way you handle connections is a bit odd, and makes it very easy to leak connections. You might just want to obtain a connection from the data source when you really need it, and learn about try-with-resources so you close it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am closing the connections whenever I done with it. But as I mentioned above comment, tomcat does not reusing sleeping connections somehow. So making maxTotal 10-20 will cause to not responding any request. And there is another issue that you missed. I said that sleeping connections counts increases up to thousands. So does Tomcat really keeps thousands of connection ready to give whenever someone asked?? It is clear that there is some other thing wrong here. But could not find out what it is.

Comment: @JollyRoger Then the way you handle closing connections is probably wrong and leaking connections.

Comment: That is why I wrote the way how I handle the closing connection situation. Can you see any leak there?

Comment: @JollyRoger Your code would be so much simpler if you would get your connections directly from a data source and using try-with-resources instead of using such a wrapper around your connection + statement. Your code as shown doesn't seem to leak connections, but the problem you describe indicates that you are leaking connections.

Comment: Yes, there is a leaking absolutely but since this code does not belongs to me, I can not make a big difference unfortunately. What can be the other reasons for connection leak?

Comment: @JollyRoger Besides bugs in the connection pool implementation, the only reason I can think of is not closing the connection in all execution paths.

Comment: I do not think that there are bugs in the pool implemetation because It uses Tomcat 8.5 and my other applications also uses it, they do not have this problem. And as I said in question, in the first part of my code that I shared leaks a connection evet it implemented correctly. So I could not rid of this unfortunately :( Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @JollyRoger Other option might be code calling `openConnection` explicitly if a connection is already open (it doesn't check `isOpen`). Or under concurrent access from multiple threads it is possible that multiple connections get opened because of race conditions and thread visibility of `isOpen`, etc.